# Difference frameworks to do face matching

Tags: opencv, face-recognition, conv-neural-network, facenet

I try to make the correspondence between two faces and give as a result if two faces match or not.
To do this, I did some research and I found the face comparison package (https://pypi.org/project/face-compare/) that allows me to do this, and it works very well which is based on FaceNet. But here, I want to compare the accuracy of this solution with other solutions to choose the best one. Can anyone have an idea of other solutions (open source or commercial) that can help me for this benchmark

Answer (score 1):

The [FaceNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832.pdf) work should be a good start. The network does a good feature matching for the facial data. Even though the face-compare library uses the same model, it would be good if you can fine-tune the FaceNet model on another dataset and evaluate with respect to the output form face-compare.

Apart from that, different variants of siamese architecture can be tried for feature matching. If you want to compare the matching, try getting the triplet loss value for set of images.

Comment: thank you @ravikt  for your answer. Did IBM cloud ,Google cloud, Azure ML or AWS provides the matching functionality ? I did a research but I founded that only the face recognition  is provided by those companies, is this true ?

Comment: @HoussemElAbed I am not sure what applications those companies provide. Probably most of them won't disclose all the details about the method they use. However, most of the state-of-the-art algorithm does facial recognition by doing the matching. Even FaceNet does the same.